# Dual boot issue

Tags: dual-boot

When I installed Juno, I already had Win7 and Loki running. I wanted to replace Loki with Juno but was not given that choice. It was "run alongside" or "replace all." Now I have all three running, which crowds my little notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove Loki and Juno partition from the installer and start fresh.